# Simulating GDI+ gamma correction in QT

Tags: qt, gdi+, lineargradientbrush

I need to implement some GDI+ functionality in QT, particularly, a [LinearGradientBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534473%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The only method that I have troubles with is [SetGammaCorrection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535345%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I found a topic that mentioned that MSDN has a pretty thorough description of GDI+ gamma correction algorithm, but I couldn't find it.

I tried to simulate gamma correction as follows:

1) Suppose we have a simple LinearGradientBrush with two-color interpolation. Divide the interval between these two colors into a predefined number of points (100) with equal distance between each point.

2) Assign a value to each point. First point will have a value of 0, second--0.01, ..., the last point will have a value of 1.

3) Calculate an interpolated color value in each point:

```
current_color = start_color * (1 - current_point_value) + end_color * current_point_value;
```

Start color and end color are the gradient boundary colors, if it wasn't clear enough.

4) Perform actual gamma correction on each calculated color value (except the two boundary colors):

```
gamma_corrected_color_value = color_value ^ (1 / gamma);
```

The value of gamma is 2.2.

Then I take the QLinearGradient, make an array of gradient stops with calculated colors and their positions (point values), assign those stops to the gradient and finally create a QBrush with this gradient.

Now if I fill a rectangle with this brush, I get a result that is pretty close to the result of actual GDI+ LinearGradientBrush, but they are not the same. I have tried a different combinations of gamma values and number of segments, but I didn't manage to get almost equal gradients.

Does anyone know how the gamma correction is implemented in GDI+ or how to simulate it in QT?

Thanks, Tony.

Comment: How far off were your results? Microsoft is one of the originators of sRGB, perhaps they used that formula instead of a straight gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

Qt gradients are linear, gamma is non-linear. Looks like you're going to have to regenerate the gradient whenever the gamma changes -- as opposed to having the gamma be a parameter of the gradient.

Comment: Yeah, this is the way it works. But there is no problem with gradient generation process. The problem is that gamma correction algorithm used by me produces slightly different results than actual GDI+ LinearGradientBrush. I want to achieve the maximum similarity of those results.